# XSL finding the correct uncle when there are many uncles

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML (much abbreviated)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="uncle.xsl"?>
<report>
<title>Bibliography</title>
<dateCreated>2016-07-21T10:33:22</dateCreated>
<dateFormat>yyyy/mm/dd</dateFormat>
    <catalog>
        <marc>
            <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="00">Title 1</marcEntry>
        </marc>
        <call>
            <callNumber>Call_1_VALLA</callNumber>
            <item>
                <itemID>item_1_VALLA</itemID>
            </item>
        </call>
        <call>
            <callNumber>Call_2_VALLA</callNumber>
            <item>
                <itemID>item_2_VALLA</itemID>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemID>item_2_2_VALLA</itemID>
            </item>
        </call>
        <call>
            <callNumber>Call_3_CNB</callNumber>
            <item>
                <itemID>item_3_CNB</itemID>
            </item>
        </call>
    </catalog>
    <catalog>
        <marc>
            <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="04">Title 2</marcEntry>
        </marc>
        <call>
            <callNumber>Call_4_VALLA</callNumber>
            <item>
                <itemID>item_4-VALLA</itemID>
            </item>
        </call>
        <call>
            <callNumber>Call_5_CNB</callNumber>
            <item>
                <itemID>item_5_CNB</itemID>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemID>item_5_2_CNB</itemID>
            </item>
        </call>
    </catalog>
</report>
```

I want to combine each itemID with the nearest preceding "uncle" (callNumber) so I get a list like this:
Title 1 Call_1_VALLA    item_1_VALLA

Title 1 Call_2_VALLA    item_2_VALLA

Title 1 Call_2_VALLA    item_2_2_VALLA

Title 1 Call_3_CNB  item_3_CNB

Title 2 Call_4_VALLA    item_4-VALLA

Title 2 Call_5_CNB  item_5_CNB

Title 2 Call_5_CNB  item_5_2_CNB

I created a stylesheet - but, it picks the first uncle instead of the nearest preceding.

Title 1 Call_1_VALLA    item_1_VALLA

Title 1 Call_1_VALLA    item_2_VALLA

Title 1 Call_1_VALLA    item_2_2_VALLA

Title 1 Call_1_VALLA    item_3_CNB

Title 2 Call_4_VALLA    item_4-VALLA

Title 2 Call_4_VALLA    item_5_CNB

Title 2 Call_4_VALLA    item_5_2_CNB

Those are the relevant parts of my stylesheet - what needs to be improved?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:template match="/">
    <catalog>

        <xsl:for-each select="report/catalog/call/item">

                        <itemline>
                            <Title><xsl:value-of select="../../marc/marcEntry[@tag='245']"/></Title>
                            <callNumber><xsl:value-of select="../../call/callNumber"/></callNumber>
                            <itemID><xsl:value-of select="itemID"/></itemID>
                        </itemline>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </catalog>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the output of the `callNumber` to this...

```
<callNumber><xsl:value-of select="../callNumber"/></callNumber>
```

Or maybe this

```
<callNumber><xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::callNumber"/></callNumber>
```